# Beginner PHP help needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, delimiter

I have been learning PHP for some time now and I wanted one clarification.

I have seen the `preg_match` function called with different delimiting symbols like:

```
preg_match('/.../')
```

and

```
preg_match('#...#')
```

Today I also saw `%` being used.

My question is two part:

**What all characters can be used?**

**And is there a standard ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any

- non-alphanumeric
- non-whitespace and
- non-backslash ASCII character

can be used as delimiter.

Also if you using the *opening* punctuation symbols as opening delimiter:

```
( { [ <
```

then their corresponding *closing* punctuation symbols must be used as closing delimiter:

```
) } ] >
```

The most common delimiter is `/`.
But sometimes it's advised to use a different delimiter if a `/` is part of the regex.

Example:

```
// check if a string is number/number format:
if(preg_match(/^\d+\/\d+$/)) {
  // match
}
```

Since the regex contains the delimiter, you *must* escape the delimiter found in the regex.

To avoid the escaping it is better to choose a different delimiter, one which is not present in the regex, that way your regex will be *shorter and cleaner*:

```
if(preg_match(#^\d+/\d+$#))
```

Comment: Just to add: if you are not using the opening/closing punctuation symbols, then the first character in your expression must be the same as the last character, else you get an error.