# What is the regular expression for this condition?

Tags: php, regex

i want the regular expression to sanitize my data which should meet the following condition

```
a) a-z and A-Z allowed

b) 0-9 allowed

c) Special Symbols like Comma (,) dot (.) question Mark (? allowed)

d) Single Space is allowed
```

i tried and came up with this

```
preg_replace('%[^a-zA-Z0-9,.?\s]%', '', $string);
```

i am not so familiar with RegExp, although the above code works, i would like to know

> a) if i am using the correct RegExp
>   syntax?
>
> b) if i don't use `modulus(%)` at the
>   start and end of the syntax it won't
>   work, and i have no idea what is the
>   purpose of modulus here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) If it works, it's correct.

b) "When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character" - from [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: oh, so you mean to say i could use any other symbols like * ( $ etc instead of modulus. wow, that's awesome, in preg_match() ealier i have used `/^[0-9]$/` so does the two forward slashes here serve the same purpose?

Comment: @Ibrahim Azhar Armar, yes that's correct. Useful in situations where you want to match against a character you may have otherwise needed to escape: `/^[0-9]%$/` vs `%^[0-9]\%$%`

Answer (score 2):

If you are requirement is to allow any single **whitespace** ( which includes space, newline, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed etc) then your regex is correct. But if you want to allow only spaces then change the `\s` to . 
The call the `preg_replace` deletes all non-allowed characters from the input.

The `%` in the call to `preg_replace` are used as regex delimiters. The `preg_` family of functions expect the regex to be within a pair of delimiters. [My answer here talks more on what can be used as delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352377/beginner-php-help-needed/4352384#4352384).

Comment: I tried to edit this to clarify that \` \` is a single space character, but SO's hacked up "Markdown" parser swallowed the whole escaped space. I've battled with Jeff before to try to get bugs in the MD parser fixed, to no avail; so I'll just note that I tried.

Answer (score 1):

**\s is a whitespace character. Which includes tabs.**

Also, if you can allow underscores, \w might make it a bit simpler

```
\w = [a-zA-Z0-9_]   // \w is a "word" character (including underscores)
```

Comment: \w sounds good instead of a-zA-Z , does this include 0-9 too?

Comment: @Ibrahim, yes, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (lowercase alpha, uppercase alpha, digits and the underscore).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape dot, comma, and question mark

`[^a-zA-Z0-9\,\.\?\s]`

Comment: i understand escaping, but i would appreciate if you explain me on why i should be escaping it? it works well without escaping it

Comment: dot (.) matches with any character. So it may create problems. But yes may be in this case escaping may not be required since it is in square brackets.

Comment: Incorrect. A dot & ? inside a character class is treated literally.

Comment: the only characters that need to be escaped in a character class are: the caret (`^`), hyphen (`-`), end bracket (`]`), and backslash (`\`); the hyphen and end bracket need not be escaped if they're the first character of the character class; the caret need not be escaped if it's *not* the first character; and the backslash is an escape character, so it will always need to be escaped, lest it escape the character following it. Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html